# Generate some div by other div's ngIf

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a table with headers and data rows.

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys; let isFirst=first">
    <div *ngFor="let entry of TableMap[key.id]">
        <ng-container *ngIf="checkIfThereIs(entry)">
          <div *ngIf="isFirst" class="display-flex">
              <div> Name </div>
              <div> Date </div>
              <div> Place </div>
              <div> Weight </div>
              <div> Height </div>
            </div>
            <div class="colorblue">
                <div class="border-r">
                    <div class="fit-content">
                        <p>{{key.name}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flexbasis13">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="flexbasis13">
                    <input type="number"/>
                </div>
                <div class="flexbasis13">
                    <input type="number"/>
                </div>
                <div class="flexbasis13">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a ngFor that creates the data rows (key of keys), a ngFor that shows the entry after key.id is sent to service, and a *ngIf="checkIfThereIs(entry)" that is checking if there is entry or not.

What I need is to pass true or false from *ngIf="checkIfThereIs(entry)" to headers div so it will show only if there is any entry. But I must go around the other ngIf and ngFor.

Comment: What if you move header div below ng-container and only display it once by using a "first" index on let key of keys.  <div ngFor="let key of keys; let isFirst=first">.  on header div use *ngIf="isFirst"

Comment: That's definitely a job for the components code, not the template code.

Comment: @Farasi78 its still generating multiple times

Comment: Can you update the code..so I can see it all?

Comment: Sure, i will what i can do

Comment: @JohnTheoden just copy / paste your modified template code in... I don't need to see everything...

Comment: @Farasi78 Check now ....it this case, header is not showing, but rows will

Comment: Hmm... try it just above ng-container.  I imagine this happens because if the first one for checkIfThereIs(entry) is false, it will never show

Comment: Hmm...still happens same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169872/discussion-between-farasi78-and-john-theoden).